# home-brew not installing on macOS Monterey

Tags: homebrew, macos-monterey

I am getting below error . Any suggestions to fix this?

==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 32a3e1fe2 Merge pull request #12488 from carlocab/service-on_os
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'

Answer (score 0):

Brew installed successfully towards the end after throwing the error `fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision`

Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.
Instructions on how to configure your shell for Homebrew
can be found in the 'Next steps' section below.
==> Installation successful!